# I have my android app compiling in an emulator, now what?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I going through a simple tutorial to create a very small android app in eclipse. The tutorial is here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-development/.

Now that I have it compiling, what should I do to get it on my phone? Do I need to export the app to some sort of exe? can i just copy and paste that exe into some "app" folder on my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to just follow these directions:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Answer (score 0):

Unless I need real-time debugging, I find it's pretty quick just to squirt the .apk at my phone and hit a few buttons to install and run it. I use Bluetooth which is fast and clean.

I have a file transfer utility for my PC's BT adapter and I simply 'push' the .apk file (from the bin directory) to my phone. Once received, I select it and it's automatically identified as an app package and I'm asked if I want to install it. Once installed I'm asked if I want to run it.

It's great when playing with samples/tutorials which (hopefully) should be bug-free and also when I'm playing around with layouts and UI elements in my own apps.

Comment: Unless you have something against enabling usb debugging to permit usage of adb, it's even easier to type "adb install whatever.apk"